# PDFtk: Merge PDF Problems

Tags: pdftk

I am using PDFtk (Version 2.02, UNIX) for merging PDF and facing below problems in the output PDF:

1. Initial View of the PDF is changed (should open with Bookmarks Panel and Page)
2. Bookmarks doesn’t point to the exact linked section as in the separate PDFs (shows fit page of the section)
3. Original metadata is lost (should retain first PDF's metadata)

Please suggest any workaround for the above points.

Regards,
Umesh

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late to answer, but I came across this question while looking for a solution to the same problem. After taking a look at the `man` of `pdftk` I found a solution and I made a little script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# pdfcat

array=( $@ )
len=${#array[@]}
merged=${array[$len-1]}
pdf2merge=${array[@]:0:$len-1}

pdftk $1 dump_data output metadata
pdftk $pdf2merge cat output $merged
pdftk $merged update_info metadata output out
mv out $merged
rm metadata
exiftool $merged
```

The script save the metadata of the first PDF file (first argument) and write it to a file called `metadata`. Then it uses the `cat` command of `pdftk` to merge all the files (the output file is the last argument). Finally it loads `metadata`'s content to the metadata of the resulting file before erasing `metadata`. The last line uses `exiftool`to print the metadata of the resulting file in order to check if everything went well.

---

You can save this script to your `home/username/bin` directory, make it executable with:

```sh
$ chmod u+x scriptname
```

and then you can use it to merge files with the following syntax:

```
$ scriptname 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf output.pdf
```

The resulting `output.pdf` will have the same metadata as the original `1.pdf` file.